# How to make formcheckbox checked and disabled dynamically?

Tags: javascript, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I have multiple checkboxes now I want to make one of them checked dynamically and it's not clickable (readonly) using the PDFkit.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
// create a document and pipe to a blob
var doc = new PDFDocument();
var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());

doc.initForm();

doc.formCheckbox('checked', 45,50,16,16, {
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
})

// end and display the document in the iframe to the right

doc.end();
stream.on('finish', function() {
  iframe.src = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');
});
```

Repo here: [demo nodejs](https://github.com/LodiLofa/pdf)
How can I make this checkbox be checked automatically and make it disabled so that the user can not check or uncheck the checkbox? any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: on the browser there is a bug about initializing the form meaning it does not work on browser, u need to run it on node js

Comment: u can test on your machine using node js here is repo : https://github.com/LodiLofa/pdf